# A* search algorithm infinite loop

Tags: algorithm, search, 2d, a-star

Like the title says, This A* search algorithm never stops searching. I'm trying to create a working A* search algorithm for point-click walking in a 2D tile-based game, some tiles are walk-able and some tiles are solid.

PathFinder.java:

```
public class PathFinder {

public static List<Node> findPath(Map map, int sx, int sy, int dx, int dy) {
    if(map.getTile(dx, dy).isSolid()) return null;
    Node startNode = new Node(new Vector2i(sx, sy), null, 0, 0);
    Vector2i goal = new Vector2i(dx, dy);

    List<Node> open = new ArrayList<>();
    HashSet<Node> closed = new HashSet<>();
    open.add(startNode);

    while(open.size() > 0) {
        Node currentNode = open.get(0);

        for(int i = 1; i < open.size(); i++) {
            if(open.get(i).fCost < currentNode.fCost || 
                    open.get(i).fCost == currentNode.fCost && open.get(i).hCost < currentNode.hCost) {
                currentNode = open.get(i);
            }
        }
        open.remove(currentNode);
        closed.add(currentNode);

        if(currentNode.tile == goal){
            System.out.println("returning path!");
            return retracePath(startNode, currentNode);
        }
        for(Tile tile : map.getNeighbors(currentNode)) {
            Vector2i neighbor = new Vector2i(tile.getTileX(), tile.getTileY());
            if(tile.isSolid() || getNodeInHashSetForPosition(neighbor, closed) != null) {
                continue;
            }

            double gCost =  currentNode.gCost + getNodeDistance(currentNode.tile, neighbor);

            if(currentNode.gCost < gCost || !vecInList(neighbor, open)) {
                double hCost = getNodeDistance(neighbor, goal);
                Node node = new Node(neighbor, currentNode, gCost, hCost);
                if(!open.contains(node)) {
                    open.add(node);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static List<Node> retracePath(Node startNode, Node endNode) {
    List<Node> path = new ArrayList<>();
    Node currentNode = endNode;

    while(currentNode !=  startNode) {
        path.add(currentNode);
        currentNode = currentNode.parent;
    }

    List<Node> finalPath = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = path.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        finalPath.add(path.get(i));
    }

    return finalPath;
}

private static boolean vecInList(Vector2i vec, List<Node> list) {
    for(Node n : list) {
        if(n.tile.equals(vec)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean vecInList(Vector2i vec, HashSet<Node> list) {
    for(Node n : list) {
        if(n.tile.equals(vec)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static Node getNodeInHashSetForPosition(Vector2i position, HashSet<Node> hashSet) {
    for(Node n : hashSet) {
        if(n.tile.equals(position)) return n;
    }
    return null;
}

private static double getNodeDistance(Vector2i nodeA, Vector2i nodeB) {
    int dstX = Math.abs(nodeA.x - nodeB.x);
    int dstY = Math.abs(nodeA.y - nodeB.y);

    if(dstX > dstY) return 14 * dstY + 10 * (dstX - dstY);
    return (14 * dstX) + (10 * (dstY - dstX));
}
}
```

Node.java

```
public class Node {

public Vector2i tile;
public Node parent;
public double fCost, gCost, hCost; //a cost is like the distance it takes to get to that point. these are used to find the lowest cost way to get from start point A to end point B.
//gCost is the sum of all of our node to node, or tile to tile, distances.
//hCost is the direct distance from the start node to the end node.
//fCost is the total cost for all the ways we calculate to get to the end node/tile.

public Node(Vector2i tile, Node parent, double gCost, double hCost) { //NODE CONSTRUCTOR STARt
    this.tile = tile;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.gCost = gCost;
    this.hCost = hCost;
    this.fCost = this.gCost + this.hCost;
}//NODE CONSTRUCTOR END
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with the debugger?

Comment: I just stepped through with the debugger and fixed the infinite loop problem and now the problem is that the size of the open list is becoming zero before reaching the endNode.

Comment: Just realized my mistake, Its a pretty silly one that took awhile to catch. if(currentNode.tile == goal){ Should have been: if(currentNode.tile.equals( goal){. Thanks For the help Zhong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the following:

```
            if(!open.contains(node)) {
```

to:

```
            if(!veckInList(neighbor, open) {
```